# Trigger is executing from the starting point for each trigger context

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I have below a trigger on account. I am using Custom setting to bypass the validation rule. I have deactivated all the Process builders. There are no workflows on Account.

**What I am doing?**

I am doing a mass update which is a temporary fix, no permanent fix required.

***the code I am executing using workbench - START***

```
set<id> setInactiveUserAccIds = new set<id>();
list<Account> accList = new list<Account>();

System_Settings__c ss =System_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();

ss.Validation_Rule_Active__c = false;

update ss;

for(User u : [Select id, isActive, AccountId from User where isActive = true and AccountId != null and Account.Is_Community__c = true limit 9000]){
                
    setInactiveUserAccIds.add(u.AccountId);
                
    Account acc = new Account(id = u.AccountId);
    acc.Is_Community__c = false;
    accList.add(acc);
}

system.debug('setInactiveUserAccIds--'+ setInactiveUserAccIds.size());

system.debug('accList--'+ accList.size());

system.debug('cs---'+ System_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults().Validation_Rule_Active__c);

if(!accList.isEmpty()) update accList;
ss.Validation_Rule_Active__c = true;

update ss;
```

***the code I am executing using workbench - END***

**The issue**

1. Tigger is getting executed again and again. There is a debug "coming in trigger" present as a 1st line in AccountTrigger, it is coming 40 times and CPU timeout exception is coming. Why Salesforce is executing it again and again? How to stop it?

Please help.

[image]

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, after insert, before update, after update, before delete, after delete, after undelete){
    //TriggerDispatcher.run(new AccountTriggerHandler());
    system.debug('coming in trigger' );
    private static AccountTriggerHandler accoutTriggerHandler;
    if(accoutTriggerHandler == null)
        accoutTriggerHandler = new AccountTriggerHandler();
    system.debug('accoutTriggerHandler.TRIGGEREXCEEDEDMAXCOUNT-- '+ accoutTriggerHandler.TRIGGEREXCEEDEDMAXCOUNT);
    if(!accoutTriggerHandler.TRIGGEREXCEEDEDMAXCOUNT && !accoutTriggerHandler.isDisabled()){
        accoutTriggerHandler.run();
    }
}
```

Trigger Dispatcher

[Trigger framework recommended by Salesforce](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework/blob/master/src/classes/TriggerHandler.cls). I have added isDisabled() in the handler to check whether the trigger is being disabled using Custom Metadata.

TriggerHandler

```
public override void beforeUpdate(){
    List<Account> newItems = (list<Account>)(Trigger.new);
    Map<Id, Account> oldItemsMap = (Map<Id, Account>)(Trigger.oldMap);
    Map<Id, Account> newItemsMap = (Map<Id, Account>)(Trigger.newMap);
    Map<Id, Account> triggerOldMap = new map<Id, Account>();
    List<Account> accountList =new List<Account>();
    List<Account> updatedaccountList =new List<Account>();

    /*for (Account accRecord: (list<Account>)oldItemsMap.values()) { 

        triggerOldMap.put(accRecord.id, accRecord);
    }*/
    system.debug('oldItemsMap--'+ oldItemsMap); 
    //further code but not going beyond it
```

Comment: The fact that triggers are run on every sub-set of 200 records shouldn't be a surprise here. That's how Salesforce has always worked in my 8 years of working on the platform. To help you move forward, I think the important question is "do you want your `AccountTrigger` trigger to be run for this operation, yes or no?"

Comment: Thanks @DerekF.1.  I am testing this in Full Sandbox, to learn if anything related to trigger code happens e.g. bulk update on the account which updates the same field mentioned in the trigger. Then how things will behave. Currently, it is failing. Yes, that is the secondary moto of this testing. Do you have any comment on the same?

Comment: @DerekF, if SF is chunking down in 200, then it should reset all limits for each chunk, which is not happening. Is there a way to reset all limits just like in batch processing dividing a transaction in separate tranxs. I know it can't happen. Just asking.

Comment: You need to write a batch class. Bulk updates using anonymous Apex will almost never work because that's how limits work on the platform.

Comment: @Rohit - Limits are per transaction, not per trigger chunk